# How would I write this better in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm new to Ruby, and I'm wondering what is a more 'Ruby' way to write this code. I don't know if my syntax is even correct. Your help is much appreciated.

Also, if I want to run this on a Mac terminal, should I command 'ruby eulerfunction.rb'?

eulerfunction.rb:

```
def gcd(n1, n2)
  x, y = n1, n2

  if x > y
    #switch them#
    t = x
    x = y
    y = t
  loop
    k = x / y
    r = x % y
    if r == 0
      break
    puts x + " = " + k + "x" + y + " + " + r
    x = y
    y = r
  puts "gcd(" + n1 + "," + n2 + ") = " + y

def eulerf(n)
  count = 0
  for (i = 1; n -1; i++)
    if gcd(n, i) == 1
      count++
  puts "Eulerf(" + n + ") = " + count
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to the site! This isn't a great question for StackOverflow. I recommend you read [the entire Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and head back when you have a specific, programming-related question.

Comment: Don't expect people to decipher your code. Explain what it is supposed to do. If you don't even know if your code is correct, then how are people supposed to know what it does?

Comment: When you ask for help making working code better, the question moves to be on-topic for [codereview.se] and off-topic for [so].

Answer (score 1):

Ruby has a gcd method; the Ruby way would be to use it:

```
20.gcd(30) #=> 10
```

Answer (score -1):

A few points:

- **There is no ruby way** I know people will use this a lot but it's not an actual "official" term.
- That being said, what I usually see on ruby code that is considered "good" (very subjective term btw) is clear variable names (so try and avoid things like `r` or `gcd`), this clears confusion as in your code I only know what they are since I know what your code is doing, which won't always be the case.
- Learn the ruby syntax, it's not overly complicated and will get you a better answer. I reccomend you start with this http://tryruby.org/levels/1/challenges/0

And most importantly as mentioned in the comments, questions on SO that are likely to have very subjective answers are not going to go very far. If you have something specific and quantifiable you are much more likely to get an answer. Also, please put effort into your code examples (i.e. learning the syntax) and be very clear both to yourself and the people answering your questions as to what exactly you want.